# C Syntax :: Function passed as parameter, where does function get its arguments?

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I’m reading through the C code for nDPI, a network packet inspection program.  ([available her](https://github.com/ntop/nDPI)e)  Most of the raw code I can follow, but this line threw me (slightly abridged for this forum):

```
if(pcap_loop(1, 2, &ndpi_process_packet, 3) < 0)
      printf("Error while reading pcap file!\n");
```

So the `if()` statement is wrapped around a call to `pcap_loop`.  Its that reference to “`&ndpi_process_packet`” that I am wondering about.  It turns out that “`ndpi_process_packet()`” is a function, defined elsewhere in the code:

```
static void ndpi_process_packet(u_char *args,
                                const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
                                const u_char *packet) {
   ...blah blah blah...
}
```

Embedding `printf()` statements makes me think that the first line is calling `pcap_loop`, and passing the address of “`ndpi_process_packet()`” as a parameter.  I understand the general concept of passing a function as a parameter, but here it confuses me.

And here’s what flummoxes me:  “`ndpi_process_packet()`” requires three arguments.  But as far as I can tell, the “`if()`” line doesn’t provide any.  So how are those arguments being submitted to “`ndpi_process_packet()`”?  Where might I look to see where those arguments are coming from?

In case its relevant (I don’t think it is), I’ll add that the `pcap_loop` is not a function, but a goto chunk of code in another function:

```
pcap_loop:
  runPcapLoop(thread_id);
  if(playlist_fp[thread_id] != NULL) { /* playlist: read next file */
    char filename[256];
    if(getNextPcapFileFromPlaylist(thread_id, filename, sizeof(filename)) == 0 &&
       (ndpi_thread_info[thread_id].workflow->pcap_handle = pcap_open_offline(filename, pcap_error_buffer)) != NULL) {
      configurePcapHandle(ndpi_thread_info[thread_id].workflow->pcap_handle);
      goto pcap_loop;
    }
```

Any thoughts on this?  Thanks.

EDITING FOR COMMENTS...
@KamilCuk  --  Thank you, your observation is really helpful.  I scanned through the code files for all references to "pcap_loop," and I never saw a pcap_loop() function.  Forgive me, but from the code I sited, you are certain that there must be a pcap_loop() elsewhere in the project?  Can I assume the pcap_loop() function must exist, and it must be in some linked .c file or something?  Thanks!

@Barmar  --  Thank you, I'll start reading up on callback functions.  Very useful pointer.  :)

Comment: So have you ever heard of function pointers? `but a goto chunk of code` no, [`pcap_loop`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcap_loop.3pcap.html) is a function. It just happens to also be defined as a goto label in that particular part of code.

Comment: The arguments are supplied internally by the `pcap_loop()` function when it calls the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And here’s what flummoxes me:  “`ndpi_process_packet()`” requires three arguments.  But as far as I can tell, the “`if()`” line doesn’t provide any.  So how are those arguments being submitted to “`ndpi_process_packet()`”?  Where might I look to see where those arguments are coming from?

You need to look at how pcap_loop uses those arguments. As far as I can tell, pcap_loop is not defined in that project. It's part of an external library, libpcap.

So if you search libpcap, you'll find [this function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/d889564216eb4e1fdae4cb4dff687f0dd51e11f3/pcap.c#L2887-L2915):

```c
int
pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user)
```

It saves the function pointer to a variable called `callback`. So, we need to find how it uses `callback`.

Next, look at this line:

```c
n = pcap_offline_read(p, cnt, callback, user);
```

So it calls another function and passes it `callback`.

Next, find where [that function](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/d889564216eb4e1fdae4cb4dff687f0dd51e11f3/savefile.c#L617-L661) is defined:

```c
int
pcap_offline_read(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user)
```

The callback is called like so:

```c
(*callback)(user, &h, data);
```

And those are the arguments which are passed to `ndpi_process_packet()`.

Comment: --  YES!  You are completely correct.  The key insight here is that pcap_loop() is a function in the libpcap library, which I hadn't realized.  (So weird that the author of the nDPI code made a goto tag with the same name!)  Your explanation is clear and very easy to follow.  Thank you!